# How to mock module static method in ruby rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to write some rspec tests and I want to mock a static method from a module.

The setup is like this:

```
module MyModule

 def self.my_method
  'end'
 end
```

and inside rspec I want to mock my_method, like this:

```
alow_any_instance_of(MyModule).to(
 receive(:my_method).and_return('not_bla')
)
```

Inside the working code, the method is called like this: `MyModule.my_method`

When I try to use the setup from above, it gives me the following error:

> MyModule does not implement #my_method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [new syntax](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-11/docs/basics/allowing-messages) to stub messages in RSpec looks like this:

```
allow(MyModule).to receive(:my_method).and_return('not_bla')
```

The [old syntax](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-11/docs/old-syntax/stub) which is not recommended anymore looks like this:

```
MyModule.stub(:my_method).and_return('not_bla')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/modules-and-stub/168721

The solution code looks like this:

```
MyModule.stub(:my_method).and_return('not_bla')
```